# how can i solve java fatal error during jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe, hs-err

I'm using `JFrame` (window builder) with eclipse.

When I go to design tab and click components or something.  Sometimes eclipse just closes without throwing any error and when I open eclipse again my `Jframe` file is vanished in air.

I can't use the name of my `Jframe` file again.

> > 'Type with same name but different case exists.' occurs.

I found out that every time it happens new file such as `hs_err_pd13544` is created . So I copied part of it.

I tried reinstalling java and eclipse several times without any help.

```
    #
    # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
    #
    #  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffdecbcaca8, pid=13544, tid=29532
    #
    # JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (13.0.1+9) (build 13.0.1+9)
    # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (13.0.1+9, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
    # Problematic frame:
    # C  [MSCTF.dll+0x2aca8]
    #
    # No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
    #
    # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
    #   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
    # The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
    # See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
    #


    ---------------  S U M M A R Y ------------

    Command Line: -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8 -Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UseStringDeduplication --add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8 -Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true -Xms256m -Xmx1024m --add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM -Declipse.p2.max.threads=10 -Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest -Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/ -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8 -Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UseStringDeduplication --add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8 -Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true -Xms256m -Xmx1024m --add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM -Declipse.p2.max.threads=10 -Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest -Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/ 

    Host: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8265U CPU @ 1.60GHz, 8 cores, 7G,  Windows 10 , 64 bit Build 18362 (10.0.18362.329)
    Time: Thu Nov 21 13:46:57 2019 ´eCN¹I±¹ C￥AØ½A elapsed time: 77 seconds (0d 0h 1m 17s)
```

Comment: What version of eclipse? It seems like you may be using an old eclipse install, but your installed java version is quite new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)
I'm using JFrame (window builder) with eclipse.
--> For Swing frame work, Netbeans IDE is more feasible or best option due to lighter and faster than eclipse.Try the same code with Netbeans IDE.

2) Another way is..
Use New/latest version of Eclipse Or update existing eclipse.